# gsutil rsync -C "continue" option not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

gsutil rsync -C "continue" option is not working from backup_script:

```
$GSUTIL rsync -c -C -e -r -x $EXCLUDES $SOURCE/Documents/ $DESTINATION/Documents/
```

From systemd log:

```
$ journalctl --since 12:00
Jul 25 12:00:14 localhost.localdomain CROND[9694]: (wolfv) CMDOUT (CommandException: Error opening file "file:///home/wolfv/Documents/PC_maintenance/backup_systems/gsutil/ssmtp.conf": .)
Jul 25 12:00:14 localhost.localdomain CROND[9694]: (wolfv) CMDOUT (Caught ^C - exiting)
Jul 25 12:00:14 localhost.localdomain CROND[9694]: (wolfv) CMDOUT (Caught ^C - exiting)
Jul 25 12:00:14 localhost.localdomain CROND[9694]: (wolfv) CMDOUT (Caught ^C - exiting)
Jul 25 12:00:14 localhost.localdomain CROND[9694]: (wolfv) CMDOUT (Caught ^C - exiting)
```

because owner is root rather than user:

```
$ ls -l ssmtp.conf
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 1483 Jul 24 21:30 ssmtp.conf
```

rsyc worked fine after deleting the root-owned file.
This happened on a Fedora22 machine, when cron called backup_script which called gsutil rsync.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting that problem. We'll get a fix for this bug in gsutil release 4.14.

Mike